# How to get the p_Value in the summary of a linear regression model?

Tags: linear-regression, p-value

does anyone know how I get the p_Value from the summary of a model in R?
It is a linear regression model and the pciture shows the result/summary of the model. I know how to get the other values like Fstatistic or R_squared but for some reason I can't get the p_value.

Thank you!

Summary of the model

[image]

Comment: Which programming language or statistics software do you prefer?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I use RStudio.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can estimate it yourself

```
> pf(12.72,1,121,lower.tail=F)
[1] 0.0005192033
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!